# Post REST does not work from browser does not work from browser but work from postman

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, postman

REST Post does not work from browser. Everything work from Postman. But from browser I have 404 error

Comment: Are you sure that you're making a POST request in the browser? Open the Dev Tools and check. Perhaps you're unwittingly making a GET request when submitting a form, because you didn't specify POST as the method.

Comment: https://localhost:5001/People/CreatePerson/?nickname=Max

it is my string in browser. 

DevTools shows DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbdom/include.preload.js.map

Comment: It's a GET request, not a POST request. Otherwise you wouldn't see it in the address bar. You need to change your code to use POST instead of GET.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I found a lot of information that it is the same part in string request, but after it should be: /?parametrName=value

  as I did https://localhost:5001/People/CreatePerson/?nickname=Max

Answer (score 0):

Save the following code as `index.html` and open it in the browser:

```
<form method=post action='http://localhost:5001/People/CreatePerson/'>
  <input name=nickname value=Max>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You cannot make a POST request using the address bar. The address bar should stays empty when you're doing POST requests.

Comment: I create android client. I and it is not work from there, Some man from youtube showed it from address bar and fter that made some request from client(phone). I decided that it is connected

Comment: You can also update the API. Just copy the POST route and change the copy to use GET instead. Then you will be able to call your endpoint using either POST or GET. Right now, it only accepts POST; that's why you can't use the address bar. Why are you using it anyway if you're building an Android client? If it's for testing, just use Postman.

Comment: I used PostMan. It is work, but it is not work from my androind client. I decided to find why, and somebody showed that it should work via address bar too

Comment: Just ask a new question and post the code that's not working. Someone will be able to help you.